# ORA-24347: Warning of a NULL column in an aggregate function

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, oracle11g, aggregate-functions

I'm getting this warning:

```
ORA-24347: Warning of a NULL column in an aggregate function
```

when using Oracle's `MAX()` function in production. I'm using the OCI library to connect to Oracle, version 11.2.0.2.

But, on the testing server, this error is not coming. I've hard-coded the query in such way that a `NULL` value can be passed to an aggregate function. I still couldn't reproduce this issue.

Is this warning related to any Oracle bug? Can anyone provide some example query which will throw this warning?

Edit:

```
Table: EX_TABLE
Columns:
ID NOT NULL NUMBER
SOME_NUMBER NUMBER
MAX_VAL NUMBER
```

Query:

```sql
select MAX(DECODE(some_number,1,max_val,NULL)) val1
     , MAX(DECODE(some_number,2,max_val,NULL)) val2
     , MAX(DECODE(some_number,3,max_val,NULL)) val3 
  from EX_TABLE
```

Comment: Can you make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)? I.e. a simple table with data and the query you use to show us. (Don't need the C++ program, just table data and the query.) Otherwise this question is almost impossible to answer.

Comment: Although I suspect it's just a typo, in the second and third lines you're taking the max of "some_numer" where I suspect you meant "some_number".

Answer (score 1):

You should decode the values with 0 not with NULL;

```
select MAX(DECODE(some_number,1,max_val,0)) val1,
       MAX(DECODE(some_numer,2,max_val,0)) val2,
       MAX(DECODE(some_numer,3,max_val,0)) val3 
  from EX_TABLE
```

Comment: yes that will solve the issue. But even though am passing NULL the warning not coming in testing server. I just want to simulate that warning.

Comment: @VijayVasanth - if you're getting the warning in production but not in development and the code is the same, I'd check to verify that the data is identical in both your development and production environments.

Comment: @Bob - Data is not identical. But here i am passing NULL then also warning is not coming. Wondering what this warning is about.

Comment: @VijayVasanth - can you copy the data from production to development so you're using the same data?  And are both the production and development environments running the exact, same version of Oracle (i.e. 11.2.0.2, with identical patches applied to each)?  I tried recreating this issue in 11.1 without success.  Looking around on the net I find this was reported as a bug at various times in Oracle versions 8 and 9 - perhaps it has crept back into 11.2?